# I want to keep all the NaN values at the end while doing sorting (ascending and Descending) - Flex Sorting

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, apache-flex

I want to keep all the NaN values at the end while doing sorting (ascending and Descending) - Flex Sorting

While both kind of sorting - (ascending and Descending) it should be at the bottom in Data grid column.

Comment: Is this a request or a question? What have you tried? What is your problem?

Comment: count all NaN values, remove them, sort, add back a count of NaN values

Comment: @ Dodger - Yes it is a question
@Andrei - Yes I tried it , but no luck with this approach.

Comment: Can the code for your failed attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom sort :

```
yourArray.sort(AscendingNaNSortingFunction);//For ascending sort.
yourArray.sort(DescendingNaNSortingFunction);//For descending sort.

function AscendingNaNSortingFunction(a:MyObject, b:MyObject):Number {
    var aAttribute:Number = a.getMyAttribute();
    var bAttribute:Number = b.getMyAttribute();

   if(isNaN(aAttribute)){
       return 1;
    }
    else if(isNaN(bAttribute)){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(aAttribute > bAttribute) {
        return 1;
    } else if(aAttribute < bAttribute) {
        return -1;
    } else  {
        //aAttribute == bAttribute
        return 0;
    }
}

function DescendingNaNSortingFunction(a:MyObject, b:MyObject):Number {
    var aAttribute:Number = a.getMyAttribute();
    var bAttribute:Number = b.getMyAttribute();

   if(isNaN(aAttribute)){
       return 1;
    }
    else if(isNaN(bAttribute)){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(aAttribute > bAttribute) {
        return -1;
    } else if(aAttribute < bAttribute) {
        return 1;
    } else  {
        //aAttribute == bAttribute
        return 0;
    }
}
```